# excel initialize 'protect/unprotect sheet' with a userform

Tags: excel, vba, logging, readonly, userform

I have made an Excel file in which operators from a manufacturing company can log malfunctions/failures or anything that stops production. The way an operator logs a malfunction, is by clicking on a button on one sheet, that opens a userform created with VBA in Excel.

The operator fills in all the required fields through dropdown menus (operators' name, team, malfunction type, machine name, etc). When the operator is finished, he or she can press on the save button which will write all the data to another sheet in a standardized way, so it is ready to be used for data visualization.

*The problem*

Some operators do not use the userform to log a malfunction, but type directly into the data sheet, which contradicts the logging of malfunctions in a standardized way. Simply hiding the sheet, or putting a password on it is not an option, because operators must be able to see all the logged malfunctions by others as well.

*Possible solution*

I have been thinking and the only solution to solve this, is to make the data-sheet readonly. But the problem that occurs then, is that the userform isn't able to put the data into the sheet as well. So i think the best way to solve this, is to put a readonly on the sheet at all times, but when the userform opens, the sheet is unprotected (so it can save the data on the sheet), and when the userform is closed it will be readonly again. Feel free to ask if you need anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Worksheet.Protect method has an option to only stop the user from changing data on the sheet. set UserInterFaceOnly to True:

Worksheet.Protect Password:="randompass" UserInterfaceOnly:=True

Then the code can change the data but the user can't

Comment: So where do i put this? in the vba code behind the userform? (Private Sub UserForm_Initialize())

Comment: Alright, your code didn't exactly work, but i managed to solve it based on what you said:
I've put a protection on the sheet that needed to be readonly and put Blad1.Unprotect pwd and Blad1.protect pwd in the save button.

Comment: This is best placed In workbook_open, so when you open your workbook, the sheet is instantly protected